# QlikView expression for last 12 months & DISTINCT & not changed by selections

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a few expressions:

```
=COUNT(SUPP)
```

Gives me 9316 which is correct as it is the total number.

```
=COUNT(DISTINCT SUPP)
```

Gives me 3429 which is correct as it is the total distinct number.

```
=ROUND(Sum( if((Date(MonthName(MMMYY),'MMM-YY')) >= (AddMonths(Today(),-13)),1,0)))
```

Gives me 396 which is correct as it is the total number for the last 12 months JAN to JAN.

```
=count({$<[Company] ={"$(=concat([Company],'","'))"}>}DISTINCT [SUPP])
```

Gives me 332 which is correct as it is the total number for the last 12 months JAN to JAN but only when i have made the date selections.

What I need:

I need the following expression:

```
=ROUND(Sum( if((Date(MonthName(MMMYY),'MMM-YY')) >= (AddMonths(Today(),-13)),1,0)))
```

To be adapted into doing two things.

1. Give the result for distinct selections which is (332)
2. Not be affected by selections.

Or using this expression :

```
=count({$<[Company] ={"$(=concat([Company],'","'))"}>}DISTINCT [SUPP])
```

To be adapted into doing two things.

1. Give the result of 332 without needing to select JAN 15 to JAN 16.
2. Not be affected by selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `{1}` prefix in the expression will ignore all selections from listboxes (or other) and the `DISTINCT` on the field that is being counted.

```
=Count({1<MMMYY ={'>=$(=Date(AddMonths(Today(), -13),'MMM-YY'))<=$(=Date(Today(), 'MMM-YY'))'}>} DISTINCT [SUPP])
```